# changing context menu items dynamically in android

Tags: android, contextmenu

I am trying to implement a contacts application. Here's the source :

```
call = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    message = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    registerForContextMenu(call);
                    openContextMenu(call);
                }
            });
    message.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            registerForContextMenu(message);
            openContextMenu(message);
        }
    });
```

Now, this is the Context menu part :

```
 public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
{
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu,v,menuInfo);
    String num1 = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.num1)).getText().toString();
    String num2 = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.num2)).getText().toString();
    if(v == call)
    {
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Call");
        menu.add(0,v.getId(),0,num1);
        if(num2 != "")
        {
            menu.add(0,v.getId(),0,num2);
        }
    }
    else if(v == message)
    {
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Message");
        menu.add(0,v.getId(),0,num1);
        if(num2 != "")
        {
            menu.add(0,v.getId(),0,num2);
        }
    }
}
```

The main functionality is , If the user has only one contact no, then only one number should be shown in the context menu. But, THIS is the problem :

[The Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmttw.png)

It shows a blank space if there's no 2nd contact no. And, it's clickable !

My LOGIC : I am using TextView for showing the numbers stored in database. And I am using String to store the data of the TextView. If the 2nd number's String is not null, then add the item to the context menu.

Please help me with this !
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know java? `num2 != ""` what it supposed to do?

Comment: If the `num2` is not null, i.e If the contact has 2nd number then add it to context menu, else don't add it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In java you should use

```
!num2.isEmpty()
```

instead of

```
num2 != ""
```

String comparision is done like

```
string1.equals(string2) ; //to match 2 strings
string.isEmpty() //to check if string is empty
```

in java.

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Best one is..

```
  if(num2.trim().lenght()>0)
    {
        menu.add(0,v.getId(),0,num2);
    }
```